# Why doesn't this Facebook share code work?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

I'm trying to make a custom Facebook share function for my website, and I'm using the Facebook sharer URL to open Facebook share in a popup window. However, for some reason it doesn't work.

What I'm doing is simple:

```
function shareFB(){
    var img=$('#fb_img').html();
    var text=$('#fb_share').html();
    var url=$('#fb_url').html();

    var full_url='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=MyTitle&amp;p[summary]='+text+'&amp;p[url]='+url+'&amp;&p[images][0]='+img;

    window.open(full_url, 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');
}
```

The weird thing is, it doesn't matter what values I give to `img`, `text` and `url` or even if I use all of them. In the example below, I removed `img` completely and set `text="whatever"` and `url="http://www.domain.com/stats_leagues.php"`.

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&amp%3Bp[title]=SportFant&amp%3Bp[summary]=whatever&amp%3Bp[url]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Fstats_leagues.php
```

Yet it doesn't work - it just opens an empty popup. Why? I've used the same URL format for Facebook shares a dozen times and it always worked. Even copy/pasting the formatted URL above into my browser just opens a blank page.

Comment: Why don't you just use JS code provided by Facebook? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/

Comment: If pasting the URL into your browser directly doesn't work, then the URL is wrong, not the Javascript.

Comment: @Glavić Because the client doesn't want it and there are other reasons which really don't matter here.

Comment: @Nunners Agreed, but what is wrong with it. It's the exact same URL I used before.

Comment: @jovan: [this url](https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=SportFant&p[summary]=whatever&p[url]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Fstats_leagues.php) works for me.

Comment: @Glavić: this URL doesn't take the custom title while sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know from where you got all those parameters, like `s=`, `p[title]`, etc., probably from some old version of facebook share?

On Facebook [share button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/) docs, under FAQ, it says:

> Yes, although we recommend using the Share button to offer the simplest and most consistent experience for people using your site, you can invoke the Share Dialog using a link: `<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fparse.com" target="_blank">`

So just change your code to:

```
function shareFB() {
    var url = $('#fb_url').html(); #encode url if it is not already
    var full_url = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+url; 
    window.open(full_url, 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');
}
```

FAQ also states that Facebook will scrape your page for additional info, like title, image, etc. It scrapes your OG meta tags from your page. Debug it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/).

Comment: The whole point is that I want to add a custom description to the share :) I don't want it to grab the page title and page description.

Comment: @jovan: that can be accomplished, by sending message in your url, and just add it to your `og:description` tag. Something like that `http://shared.domain.com/?og_description=TEXT`...

Comment: @jovan: does this work for you? Or have you found other solution?

Comment: I have fixed my code, the parameters were fine but there was a stray "&" in there which was breaking it.

Comment: @jovan: Can you please paste the url? because custom parameters are not working for me anymore